# BlackBerry 10 Native SDK - CellID always returns 0

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, cellular-network, blackberry-ndk

CellID &  LocationAreaCode always return zero on my device:

*Sample Code:*

```
    int cellId = bb::device::CellularNetworkInfo().cellId();
    int LAC = bb::device::CellularNetworkInfo().locationAreaCode();
```

The above will *ALWAYS* be zero

Strangely signal strength does return a valid value (eg -90):

*Sample Code:*

```
    int signalStrength = bb::device::CellularNetworkInfo().signalStrength();
```

I am on a GSM network, but just for interests sake I tried networkId & systemId and they still returned zero

*Extra Info:*
I have #include bb/device/CellularNetworkInfo in the hpp
In my pro file I added: LIBS += -lbbdevice
The device is connected to the network (can make calls etc)
I have ticked all the permissions in the bar-descriptor
I used [this as a reference](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__device__cellularnetworkinfo.html#function-systemidchanged-sid)

Has anyone got values for CellID & LAC?
Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cite:

Identifier for the geographic region which contains the base station serving the GSM/UMTS network.
Permissions:
The application must have the *read_radio_modem_data* permission to access this information.

Adding this to your bar-descriptor.xml will solve this issue:

```
<permission>read_radio_modem_data</permission>
```

Comment: It works! Adding <permission>read_radio_modem_data</permission> solved the issue!!

Answer (score 0):

Last extra-Info: Did you check the required authorization in the app descriptor file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I have ticked all the permissions in the bar descriptor.

Comment: Could you download the geolocation sample from github, and test it inside an buiding (no GPS) and without Wifi to force the cell-Id location. Just to know if the device fails to retrieve the cell-Id, or it just if it fails to provide the cell-id to your app.

Comment: Hi Hithredin, The geolocation works in a building(no GPS) and with out wifi.

Also to note, when I open blackberry maps, the accuracy is way out (a sign that it is starts to get a network fix, and then the more accurate gps fix kicks in)... so it appears to be my app/api problem...

Have any one else got a cell id?